# Adding a data toggle link for a modal view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi I'm creatign a site using Rails and bootstrap and I have a problem I can't seem to work out. I have a modal view I want to show when the user clicks a link in the navbar, following the bootstrap documentation I've gotten it to work using a button, but I can't seem to with a link.

It works with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          New Update
        </button>
```

and I've tried

```
<%= link_to 'New Update', '#', { 'data-toggle' => 'myModal', 'data-target' => '#myModal'} %>
```

but it doesn' seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
<%= link_to 'New Update', '#myModal', 'data-toggle' => 'modal' %>
```

Comment: Thank you this is correct, I'll accept your anser once the timer on accepting answers passes.